Fill (stretch) or scroll based on element size
Is it possible to get the stretch behavior of display: flex when min-content would not fill the page, but still have good scrolling behavior if min-content is larger than the page size?
Essentially if the behavior second code snippet doesn't fill the page, I want the behavior of the first code snippet.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector(".footer > input").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    for (d of document.querySelectorAll(".content > div")) {
      d.style.height = ((event.target.value < 0.01) ? "100%" : (event.target.value + 'rem'));
    }
  });
});
* {
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: grey;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: blue;
}

.content>div {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1rem;
  background-color: gold;
}

.footer {
  height: 2rem;
  min-height: 2rem;
  flex: 0 0 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: green;
}
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <input type="number" value=0 min=0>
  </div>
</body>





document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector(".footer > input").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    for (d of document.querySelectorAll(".content > div")) {
      d.style.height = event.target.value + 'rem';
    }
  });
});
* {
    margin: 0.5rem;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: min-content;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color: grey;
}

.content {
    height: min-content;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color: blue;
}

.content > div {
    height: 6rem;
    min-height: 1rem;
    background-color: gold;
}

.footer {
    height: 2rem;
    min-height: 2rem;
    flex: 0 0 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: green;
}
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <input type="number" value=1 min=0>
  </div>
</body>




Edit: Added input box to make the behavior easier to see. If the gold boxes are too large in the first snippet than you can't scroll to see all of the footer. In the second snippet, the blue and gold boxes will never stretch to fill the available space.

I was able to get it working. I think the key was to use min-height: 100vh instead of height: 100vh as well as using flex-grow: 1. I tried flex: 1 before making the OP, but that didn't work (I probably need to read more about flex since it's apparently preferred to use flex instead of flex-*).


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector("#footer > input").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    for (d of document.querySelectorAll(".content > div")) {
      d.style.height = event.target.value + 'rem';
    }
  });
});
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: stretch;
  background-color: gray;
}

.content {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: stretch;
  background-color: blue;
}

.content div {
  height: 2rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: solid;
  background-color: gold;
}

.footer {
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer>input {
  height: min-content;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer" class="footer">
    <input type="number" value=1 min=0>
  </div>
</div>




To achieve your desired result, we need to add some fixed height to parent/grand-parent div, in below code I have added fix height of 100vh to container.
After that you have to add height in % for all childrens/grand childrens so that it adjust to height of current window. In below code I have added height: 85%; to content , height: 27%; to footer & height: 27%; to div.
I haven't added explanation for flex usage, if you want to know more about it then please leave a reply. Thank You.


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content div {
  height: 31%;
  background-color: gold;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer center"></div>
  </div>
</body>




I don't want the space between the elements to grow, and I want the footer to be a fixed size.

Great ! , you found solution. But I have also edited code as you needed you can try. Peace

I tried to reproduce the desired, although I didn't quite understand the question:


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100dvh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.content {
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: blue;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.content > div {
  flex: auto;
  min-height: 6rem;
  background-color: gold;
}

.footer {
  min-height: 2rem;
  flex: none;
  background-color: green;
}
<div class="content">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>




It looks like the footer is partially cut off when you scroll to the bottom. I edited the OP to hopefully be more clear about the problems I was running into.
